# PHP script works in browser but times out as cron job

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, cron

I wrote a php script that basically fetches RSS feeds and stores them in a database. If I access the script through a browser, it runs flawlessly (with admittedly a two minute wait before it outputs the log), but when it runs as part of a cron Job, it produces almost 40% of the output and dies out...

I looked around the net and tried adding these two lines to my script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
```

Still same problem. I'm sure it's a settings issue because my current server is running the script as a cron-job with no problems, and my php error log is only showing a few warnings.

What's the best way to troubleshoot this problem on an ubuntu server?

### Update

I noticed that if I run the php code straight from the command line, I get perfect execution, so I think it's only a cron Job problem. Also I noticed that the execution stops whenever it wants to add new data to the MySQL database, I guess this narrows down the possibilities..

Comment: I removed it from my post, can you please remove it from your comment? thanks..

Comment: Sure, deleted ip address now. Hey, don't write ip address like this. It's not safe. I don't know how it's unsafe but i heard that file system should not be visible in browser. and if i open website.com/websites, all pages are visible and i can open files what u don't want like some file is install.php, it can be run.

Comment: is this a shared host? or one of yours and completely configurable? check if that "max_execution_time" is actually changed by ini_get()..

Comment: Try [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), if it's a shared host, you might get the security blocked this function.

Comment: one way to optimize your code and double/triple your cron job and make cron job slim. say to fetch only 40% per run. other, is to ask your hosting provider to increase it. third way to call your page with curl (if you can get with browser, you can get page with curl also). http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php I don't know solution but it can help you.

Comment: Update: If I run the php code straight from the command line, I get perfect execution, so I think it's simply only cron Job problem. Also I noticed that the running breaks whenever it wants to add new data to the MySQL database, I guess this narrows down the possibilities..

Comment: What user are you running the cron job as?

Comment: @Pekka웃 root no less..